# How to sum all cells based on each cell's row header (duplicated) and column header (duplicated) in Excel/Googlesheet?

Tags: excel, header

In Excel/Googlesheet table where row & column headers have duplicated values, how can we sum up cells in range B2:F6 by looking at each cell's row & column headers, aiming a table 
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the target table is located at A8:D11, with B8 = a, C8 = b, D8 = c  and so on for x, y, z..

1. generate helper sum table, based on a,b,c match criteria.. in H2, put `=SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,B$8,$B2:$F2)` and drag till J6 .
2. get final sum from x ,y, z criteria.. in B9 put `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,$A9,H$2:H$6)` and drag till D11.

Done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for the answer. Yet I was wondering if there's any SUMPRODUCT kind of formula solely in B9:D11 (without adding same-size table H2:J6 aside)

Comment: If you're willing to explore into array-formula.. I think can.. || I just shared a solution which I have confidence on the technique & its data integrity.. If you're willing to explore, you may possibly convert this method into a standalone 2D array formula. (I had some thoughts about it.. but just not confident on the data integrity part..)  || Btw, updated answer : correction on Step 1 formula.